# Database Sqlite insert datetime

Tags: vb.net

I have a SQL Lite database and I want to insert the time in a 24 hour system.

table

[image]

error msg
[image]

```
 Dim com As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO ROSY_TB(ROSY_CODE,ROSY_DESCREPTION,ROSY_FROM,ROSY_TO,ROSY_ALLOWFR,ROSY_ALLOWTO,ROSY_APSENTA,ROSY_APSENTB,ROSY_WORKHOUR,ROSY_APSENTNUM,ROSY_CHECK) VALUES (@ROSY_CODE,@ROSY_DESCREPTION,@ROSY_FROM,@ROSY_TO,@ROSY_ALLOWFR,@ROSY_ALLOWTO,@ROSY_APSENTA,@ROSY_APSENTB,@ROSY_WORKHOUR,@ROSY_APSENTNUM,@ROSY_CHECK)", con)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_CODE", DbType.String).Value = ROSYUPDATE_F.LAB_CODEVAL.Text
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_DESCREPTION", DbType.String).Value = ROSYUPDATE_F.TEXT_DESCREPTION.Text
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_FROM", DbType.DateTime).Value = Format(ROSYUPDATE_F.DATE_FROM.Value, "HH:mm tt") 'ROSYUPDATE_F.DATE_FROM.Value.ToLongTimeString
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_TO", DbType.DateTime).Value = Format(ROSYUPDATE_F.DATE_TO.Value, "HH:mm tt")
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_ALLOWFR", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(Val(ROSYUPDATE_F.TEXT_ALLOWFR.Text))
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_ALLOWTO", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(Val(ROSYUPDATE_F.TEXT_ALLOWTO.Text))
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_APSENTA", DbType.String).Value = ROSYUPDATE_F.COM_APSENTA.SelectedItem
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_APSENTB", DbType.String).Value = ROSYUPDATE_F.COM_APSENTB.SelectedItem
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_WORKHOUR", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(Val(ROSYUPDATE_F.TEXT_WORKHOUR.Text))
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_APSENTNUM", DbType.Int64).Value = CInt(Val(ROSYUPDATE_F.COUNTSPENT))
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROSY_CHECK", DbType.Boolean).Value = True
            con.Open()
            com.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
```

Comment: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Do you have to deal with your (Sql-mysql-sqlite-access) databases with this change..com.Parameters.AddWithValue=  > change to com.Parameters.Add

Comment: Firstly, even disregarding the fact that `AddWithValue` shouldn't be used at all (which many people don't realise) you could at leats call it properly. You clearly haven't researched this if you're calling `AddWithValue` without a value. Secondly, what's with that time format? The whole point of the "tt" is to differentiate 12-hour times. If you're using 24-hour time then what is the "tt" for? "1:23 AM" is "01:23" in 24-hour time and "1:23 PM" is "13:23". There is no "AM" or "PM" in 24-hour time. If you want to use 24-hour format then you should know what that is.

Comment: From the docs..."SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:" https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html